# Change style based on html content

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html fragment that looks like this:

```
FIELD STATUS: <span class="field-status">CLOSED</span>
```

or sometimes it might look like this:

```
FIELD STATUS: <span class="field-status">OPEN</span>
```

How would I make CLOSED be red and OPEN be green based on their content.  This is part of a larger system of which I have no control, but I can adjust the HTML source.  I think I could get a bit of jQuery in there if that's the best way.

Comment: jQuery is probably going to be your only solution if you want to do it dynamically. But you should be able to do this with html and css.

Comment: All of the answers were great.  I particularly like the concise answer @doitlikejustin presented, but the jQuery created a conflict in one of the pages where it was used and I had to go with changing changing the class manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change the HTML and CSS, you should have it set up like so,

```
FIELD STATUS: <span class="field-status closed">CLOSED</span>
FIELD STATUS: <span class="field-status open">OPEN</span>
```

```
.field-status.closed { color: red; }
.field-status.open{ color: green; }
```

To make this work in IE7 and IE8, you need to make sure you're not in quirks mode.

---

If you can't do that, you can use jQuery to add those classes.

```
$('.field-status').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this), text = $this.text(); 
    $this.addClass(text.trim().toLowerCase());
});
```

This works in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery

```
$(".field-status:contains('CLOSED')").css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: This was [removed from the CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors).  The jQuery version is valid, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CSS directly on the elements using jQuery.

```
$('.field-status').each(function() { 
   var value = $(this).text();
   if(value == 'CLOSED') {
      $(this).css('color', 'red'); 
   } else { 
      $(this).css('color', 'green'); 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you can put:

```
.field-status-open{
 color:green;
}

.field-status-closed{
color:red;
}
```

and in your HTML it is something like this:

`FIELD STATUS: <span class="field-status-closed">CLOSED</span>`

`FIELD STATUS: <span class="field-status-open">OPEN</span>`

Then you can add some script whether it should have what field class it will contain.